# Is there a some solution to use npm packages within a Magento 2 module?

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, npm

The main idea - don't keep JS files which belong to some NPM packages in a module repository?

Maybe someone have some solution of thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added NPM packages to my theme. 
The packages are installed in the `vendor/theme dir/node_modules` & then i've symlinked node_modules to `vendor/theme dir/web/node_modules`

Found at:

(https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-frontools/issues/46#issuecomment-277860180)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You can use the npm package in your Magento custom module.

I used **[@imgix/js-core](https://github.com/imgix/js-core)**. It is a JavaScript library for generating image URLs with srcset.

I followed the below steps for using the `@imgix/js-core` npm package in my custom module.

**Step1:** Go to your web directory in your module.

```
   app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web
```

**Step2:** Run the below command for creating package.json

```
npm init
```

**Step3:** After running `npm init` command, it generates package.json

```
{
    "name": "Magento 2 imigix package",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "this is a test, this is only a test",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts":
    {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "Imgix",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

**Step4:** Install `@imgix/js-core` npm package by below command

```
npm install @imgix/js-core
```

**Step5:** It will create `node_modules` directories and `package-lock.json` file.

[image: Directory structure]

**Step6:** Add js which you want to use in `requirejs-config.js`

```
// File path: app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js

var config = {
    paths: {
        ImgixClient: 'Vendor_Module/node_modules/@imgix/js-core/dist/imgix-js-core.umd'
    }
};
```

**Step7:** Now,You can access the package your module  with the below code

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'ImgixClient'
], function ($, ImgixClient) {
    .....
    // Your code

    // Generate srcset

    const client = new ImgixClient({
      domain: 'testing.imgix.net',
      secureURLToken: 'my-token',
      includeLibraryParam: false,
    });

    const srcset = client.buildSrcSet(
      'image.jpg',
      {
        h: 800,
        ar: '3:2',
        fit: 'crop',
      },
      {
        devicePixelRatios: [1, 2],
      },
    );

    console.log(srcset);
    
    .....
}):
```

**Step8:** Now, srcset generated to img tag, Check this [screenshot](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/19780638?key=770589d46809f897c15bdfca4c84ddf9) for the result.

[image]

I have used `@imgix/js-core` npm package in my custom module.

**Thanks.**

Comment: Hello @dipak i have try this way but see error into the console like this Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at defaultConfig.js:1:1) can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can install the `node_modules` directly in your theme, you don't have to create a symlink to get your node package working. There are a few places and ways to do this, but this works for me.

Create a `package.json` file with `npm init` in your web dir `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/web/package.json`. This will make it easier to install the packages and manage them in the future. This will also localize the install so that everything is in you web dir.

Install the package like normal, like `npm install shufflejs` and check you have the dep in you `package.json` file.

```
"dependencies": {
    "shufflejs": "^5.3.0"
}
```

You can then link everything together with your requireJS file.

```
//File: app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/requirejs-config.js
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            collectionsShuffle:'js/collections-shuffle',
        }
    },
    paths: {
        shufflejs: './node_modules/shufflejs/dist/shuffle'
    }
};
```

You now have access to the package anywhere in your theme with:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'shufflejs'
], function ($, shufflejs) {})
```

You might have some issues fitting in the connection with the package with the "magento" way, but play with it and you should be able to get things working.

The only downside of this approach is that `node_modules` will be tracked by git, which can be an issue in some cases, but as long as the packages are small, you will be fine. You can also set up a `.gitignore` if that is an issue.

I wrote up a more detailed walk through, you can check that out [here](https://circlesixdigital.com/how-to-add-node-packages-to-your-magento-2-site/)