# Is it possible to use npm packages in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, requirejs, npm

I see a post here from 2017 that gives an idea of how it's done, but I would want to use something like [this](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) that would allow people to sign their names on forms.

I know how to create html/js uicomponents, and include them in phtml files, but I don't know how to call functions from 3rd party libraries in those components. Any ideas on how this might be done?

Thanks

Comment: what you are trying to achive?

Comment: I'm trying to add a customer signature drawing option to some forms. I have no idea how to include this in a Magento 2 project, and call the functions

https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use the npm package in Magento 2. I used the npm package in my custom extension.

Please check this answer: [Is there a some solution to use npm packages within a Magento 2 module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194322/is-there-a-some-solution-to-use-npm-packages-within-a-magento-2-module/351812#answer-351812)

Thanks