# add node package in magento 2

Tags: magento2, pwa, react, nodejs

How to add Node packages to your Magento 2 site. how to implement in require-config.js using knockout js.

I have already applied the commands below file.

/var/www/html/project/app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/

```
npm install @web3modal/ethers5 ethers@5.7.2
```

after I add below code add require-config.js for example.

```
var config = {
paths: {
    ethers: 'Vendor_Module/node_modules/@web3modal/ethers5'
}
};
```

but my Magento frontend side does not show js. so please help me. how can I implement it?

Comment: Try this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/336039/36384 I prefer this answer rather than the accepted one. I've used this approach on several projects and it works just fine.

Comment: thanks,i am also implementing but now working. but i want to "npm install @web3modal/ethers5 ethers@5.7.2". so please help me Michigan Websites